# Why doesn't apache2 display my mailman pages?

Tags: 16.04, apache2, mailman

I've been fighting with this one for a while.  I've followed all the tutorials I can find and apache2 just doesn't display any of my mailman pages.
I'm running ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

What's the best way to further troubleshoot this?  What other information is needed?  If this isn't the correct place, where should I go for help?

Thanks!!!

Comment: What does Apache display when you try to view one of the mailman pages? Also, what gets logged when you try?

Comment: I'm looking on [Mailman Documentation](http://docs.list.org/en/latest/prodsetup.html) it looks you should setup [Reverse Proxy](https://askubuntu.com/a/1013951/566421) in Apache.